# Switch row content for row without NA in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
NAME1                NAME2                VALUE1 VALUE2 FAMILY    ORDER
Homo_sapiens_1:0-30  Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2  45     67     Hominidae Primates
Homo_sapiens_1:45-75 Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2  46     64     Hominidae Primates
Canis_lupus_1:5-66   NA                   10     35     Canidae   Carnivora 
Canis_lupus_3:23-45  Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   30     56     Canidae   Carnivora 
Canis_lupus_3:54-78  Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   23     58     Canidae   Carnivora 
Canis_lupus_3:80-99  Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   36     50     Canidae   Carnivora 
Felis_cattus_1:23-89 NA                   10     67     Falidae   Carnivora
```

and the idea is to add new `NAME1 rows` corresponding to `NAME2` values and new `NAME2` correspondign to `NAME1` only for row `without NA` in `NAME2`. . such as :

```
NAME1                NAME2                VALUE1 VALUE2 FAMILY    ORDER
Homo_sapiens_1:0-30  Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2  45     67     Hominidae Primates
Homo_sapiens_1:45-75 Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2  46     64     Hominidae Primates
Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2  Homo_sapiens_1:0-30  45     67     Hominidae Primates
Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2  Homo_sapiens_1:45-75 46     64     Hominidae Primates
Canis_lupus_1:5-66   NA                   10     35     Canidae   Carnivora 
Canis_lupus_3:23-45  Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   30     56     Canidae   Carnivora 
Canis_lupus_3:54-78  Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   23     58     Canidae   Carnivora 
Canis_lupus_3:80-99  Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   36     50     Canidae   Carnivora 
Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   Canis_lupus_3:23-45  30     56     Canidae   Carnivora 
Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   Canis_lupus_3:54-78  23     58     Canidae   Carnivora 
Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   Canis_lupus_3:80-99  36     50     Canidae   Carnivora 
Felis_cattus_1:23-89 NA                   10     67     Falidae   Carnivora
```

So as you can see I added 6 new rows corresponding to **2** `Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2` and **3**  `Canis_lupus-BLOCS3` but I switched the `NAME1` and `NAME2` content for them.
Does someone have an idea ?

Here is the dataframe in dictionnary format if it can helps :

```
{'NAME1': {0: 'Homo_sapiens_1:0-30', 1: 'Homo_sapiens_1:45-75', 2: 'Canis_lupus_1:5-66', 3: 'Canis_lupus_3:23-45', 4: 'Canis_lupus_3:54-78', 5: 'Canis_lupus_3:80-99', 6: 'Felis_cattus_1:23-89'}, 'NAME2': {0: 'Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2', 1: 'Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2', 2: nan, 3: 'Canis_lupus-BLOCS3', 4: 'Canis_lupus-BLOCS3', 5: 'Canis_lupus-BLOCS3', 6: nan}, 'VALUE1': {0: 45, 1: 46, 2: 10, 3: 30, 4: 23, 5: 36, 6: 10}, 'VALUE2': {0: 67, 1: 64, 2: 35, 3: 56, 4: 58, 5: 50, 6: 67}, 'FAMILY': {0: 'Hominidae', 1: 'Hominidae', 2: 'Canidae', 3: 'Canidae', 4: 'Canidae', 5: 'Canidae', 6: 'Falidae'}, 'ORDER': {0: 'Primates', 1: 'Primates', 2: 'Carnivora', 3: 'Carnivora', 4: 'Carnivora', 5: 'Carnivora', 6: 'Carnivora'}}
```

Comment: I don't understand the requirement

Comment: Why, though? You're just duplicating information.

Comment: because in  a programm I parse only the NAME1 column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a renamed version where you `dropna()` on `NAME2` and swap the column names `NAME1`/`NAME2`. Then `concat()` the renamed version with the original:

```py
df2 = df.dropna(subset=['NAME2']).rename(columns={'NAME1': 'NAME2', 'NAME2': 'NAME1'})
pd.concat([df, df2])

#    NAME1                 NAME2                VALUE1  VALUE2  FAMILY     ORDER
# 0  Homo_sapiens_1:0-30   Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2  45      67      Hominidae  Primates
# 1  Homo_sapiens_1:45-75  Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2  46      64      Hominidae  Primates
# 2  Canis_lupus_1:5-66    NaN                  10      35      Canidae    Carnivora
# 3  Canis_lupus_3:23-45   Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   30      56      Canidae    Carnivora
# 4  Canis_lupus_3:54-78   Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   23      58      Canidae    Carnivora
# 5  Canis_lupus_3:80-99   Canis_lupus-BLOCS3   36      50      Canidae    Carnivora
# 6  Felis_cattus_1:23-89  NaN                  10      67      Falidae    Carnivora
# 0  Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2   Homo_sapiens_1:0-30  45      67      Hominidae  Primates
# 1  Homo_sapiens-BLOCS2   Homo_sapiens_1:45-75 46      64      Hominidae  Primates
# 3  Canis_lupus-BLOCS3    Canis_lupus_3:23-45  30      56      Canidae    Carnivora
# 4  Canis_lupus-BLOCS3    Canis_lupus_3:54-78  23      58      Canidae    Carnivora
# 5  Canis_lupus-BLOCS3    Canis_lupus_3:80-99  36      50      Canidae    Carnivora
```